# Adding an Icon in a select option - Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I have a `select` with some options displaying text:

```
<select *ngIf="cars" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let car of cars" value="true">{{car.ID}}</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to add an Icon at the beginning of the option? Like [icon]3

**UPDATE**

I have added the library font-icons to my `.angular-cli.son`:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

and update the code of my `select` to:

```
<select *ngIf="cars" class="form-control glyphicon">
  <option *ngFor="let car of cars" value="true">&#xf26e; {{car.ID}}</option>
</select>
```

I use **bootstrap 3**

It tries to print an icon, but I get an empty square. Any idea?

Comment: Hello I've succeed using unicode characters, and it work :
https://codepen.io/Nagibaba/pen/bagEgx

Comment: I just need "&#xf26e;" this to my code no? Cuase it is showing just an empty square

Comment: To make it proper, use a class or style rule with font family as font awesome in case you are using this. For example class="selectUser" in HTML will have in CSS .selectUser { font-family : "FontAwesome"; content: "\f1f9 } go to font awesome cheat sheet. If you got a square you just need to import the font style with a rule like mine. To make sure only your class get it, do like I did

Comment: @MarioLópez Did you ever find a way to dynamically render a select using icons, or could you only get it to work when you hard coded the select options?

Comment: if you mean dynamically like an option with a loop, yes. I just need to add to the option the unicode of the icon that I want to use. But if you define dinamicaly in another way, I did not try it

Comment: <option *ngFor="let ro of Lookups.RatingOptions" class="{{ro.BackgroundColourVal}} {{ro.TextColour}}" [value]="ro.Id" >{{ro.IconVal}} &#xf11a; {{ro.Name}}</option>

Comment: That's what I tried but it won't render the button from iconval but will when I manually code it like the text next to it.

Comment: What I did, if I am not wrong was the following: 
 <option *ngFor="let car of cars" value="true">&#xe032; {{car.ID}}</option> and it worked (you have to have in mind that not all the fonts support unicode so maybe it wont show it if you re using one expecific font for the text)

Comment: no that's manually coded rather than dynamically as you use the same icon in each option rather than a different 1 for each

Comment: as I said it works if I manually write the icon unicode like &#xf11a will render but won't when it's output from ro.IconVal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using Bootstrap. So, it is possible to put icon inside option, like this.

```
<select class="form-control glyphicon">
    <option value="">&#xe032; Icon 1</option>
    <option value="">&#xe033; Icon 2</option>
    <option value="">&#xe034; Icon 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have a dynamic solution which matches the question?
I'm trying to do this just like Mario and dynamically render a select, if I just call the FA unicodes via {{ro.IconVal}} then I only get the iso text displayed.

Comment: @Myzifer, Icon character code renders as html not as text, so, in Angular 2+, for example, bind the content of `option` by `[innerHtml]` and it works.

Comment: I'd tried that before with no luck but I think that was due to what I was trying to implement as I had multiple values and noticed a number of issues with FA icons.
In the end I used innerHTML="{{ro.IconVal}} {{ro.Name}}" alongside directly references the FA css file from the cdn in order to get everything to almost work.
Just missing a 4th smiley face as it's part of FA 5.1 but after upgrading that still won't work.
Thanks for suggesting innerHTML as it gave me the impetious to try it again in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it is not possible using plain HTML `<select>`. It is possible with wrapper for select. Your own piece of code, that is displayed instead of browser's default `select`. I recommend you to find some library with ready-to-use wrapper. For example there is select wrapper inside Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/components/select), but you can find standalone wrappers.